# href with 2 different links but with same content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, download, href

I wanted to create a small program using tutorials on youtube to scrape download links on a video website.

but the problem is that the 'href' that hold the download links sometimes hold the same content.
In fact it's a forum, there's the link to download a video and the same video in smaller size just below. If we click on the video we are redirected to the same page that the link above redirects us.

Here is the small program:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links =[]

for p in range(21):
    url = 'website url' + str(p)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)

    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(p))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        iS = soup.findAll('i')

        for i in iS:
            a = i.find('a')
            link = a['href']
            links.append(link)

print(len(links))

with open('urls.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + '\n')


with open('urls.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        print(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Provide an example URL. In general you can make a variable that holds the last processed URL. Then before saving the next video you make an if statement that compares the new URL with the last processed, if they match you don't exectute the save.

Comment: or you make a list of saved URL:s, then use if newurl in list.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for your answer. I'll try this and I'll rest here ^^.

Comment: Oh sorry here the exemple :

Url 1 : https: //k2s.cc /file/bdb23f7468432/186Url1 .  mp4

Url2: https: //k2s.cc /file/bdb23f7468432/186Url2 utm_campaign=preview_download

Comment: both lead to the same file. Is there a way to differentiate them? For example by selecting only those with '.mp4'?

Comment: Looks like a css thing more than python.